# Published Jasper report doesn't refresh

Tags: parameters, jasper-reports, refresh, jasperserver

I have a report with one date parameter and it doesn't seem to refresh the data and regardless of what i enter, i always get the same results. this is what i have for parameter:

```
default: new Date()
class: java.util.Date
use prompt: yes
```

why the data is not getting refreshed? anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Are you talking about *JasperReports Server*?

Comment: You should post the *jrxml* file

Comment: too big, how can i do it so it fits?

Comment: and yes, i am talking about JasperReport server

Comment: You can simplify the report to reproduce your issue

Comment: how do i do it? there is no error it just populates data as of yesterday and when i change parameters it doesn't refresh data, give me the same data as of yesterday

Comment: What happens if you close the report and open it again?

Comment: First check the report whether you are passing the parameter or not?

Comment: Do you print the parameter value on report? Did you try to run the query outside of the report with the same parameters?